# Wordpress Meta Query with 3 Conditions

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a custom wordpress theme and have a pretty good grip on php & MySQL but less so on wordpress API so I'm wondering if one of you lovely people can help me out. Essentially I have this query:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'catwalk_reports_feature_on_home_page',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'product_service_feature_on_home_page',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'wedding_tips_feature_on_home_page',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
            ),
    );


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Which fails !:(

This seems to be because I have 3 arrays, when the query is performed like so:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'any',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'posts_per_page' => '3',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'catwalk_reports_feature_on_home_page',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'product_service_feature_on_home_page',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),
            ),
    );


$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

No errors, everything works as expected....

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance;

Comment: Everything you have there looks correct. This may be a dumb question, but are you sure the key `wedding_tips_feature_on_home_page` is setup correctly? Have you tried that one and one of the other keys in the 2 array query to ensure that works?

Comment: Yes I have tried 2 condition queries in all combinations with the above code and they all work fine, I think it's a problem with Wordpress' WP Query class. WP_Meta_Query() seems capable of solving the problem, however then displaying the rest of the post associated with the meta becomes a bit more problematic. Luckily, my boss is sound and said he doesn't care if it only pulls from two posts lol, still would be good to know if there is a way to pull from all three.

Answer (score 0):

can you try it this way:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'any',
  'posts_per_page' => get_option('of_an_nr20'),
  'meta_query' => array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
       array('key' => 'iframe'),
       array('key' => 'video'),
       array('key' => 'videoflv')
  )
);

$gab_query = new WP_Query();$gab_query->query($args);
while ($gab_query->have_posts()) : $gab_query->the_post();
```

Comment: Good shout! I did already try this though before posting... no dice